# How to get notified when a DIV's height changes using Knockout.js

Tags: html, knockout.js, height, observable

When the browser is resized, I have a DIV that may change in height, depending on its width. (the content will wrap).  I would like to be notified and execute a js function when the height changes.

The reason I would like to be notified is that this navigation div is "always on top".  That means I have to allow for some padding in my content div.  If the user makes the window narrow enough, the nav div will wrap and cover up the top of my content.  All I need to do at that point is get the new height of the nav div and adjust the top padding on the content div.

If I could handle this with CSS that would be even better, but not sure how.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

Coupled with updating an observable in the sensor callback, should work fine.